# Transparent table border with tr background

Tags: html, css

I use :nth-child(odd/even) selector to make different background for table rows for better readability. And now I have to set "border-spacing" or "border-color: transparent" for my table, to make background visible thru the space between cells. The problem is, that horizontal spacing should be different for different columns - the last column should have larger spacing than whole table (marked with red in the sample below).
How can I do that? Have no idea. Please help. Thank you!

```css
body
{
  background: #3a7;
}
table
{
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 5px;
  border: 0px solid #ffffff;
  margin: 1em;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
td
{
  font-size: 1rem;
  empty-cells: show;
  /*background: white;*/
  padding: 0;
}
td.last
{
  font-size: 1rem;
  empty-cells: show;
  /*background: white;*/
  /*border-left: 20px transparent;*/
  border-left: 20px solid rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}
tr:nth-child(odd)
{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    border: 0px solid transparent;
    overflow: visible;
}
tr:nth-child(even)
{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    border: 0px solid transparent;
    overflow: visible;
}
input
{
  border: 0px;
  outline: 0px transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: inherit;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><div><input></div></td>
        <td><div><input></div></td>
        <td class="last"><div><input></div></td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
        <td><div><input></div></td>
        <td><div><input></div></td>
        <td class="last"><div><input></div></td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
        <td><div><input></div></td>
        <td><div><input></div></td>
        <td class="last"><div><input></div></td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
        <td><div><input></div></td>
        <td><div><input></div></td>
        <td class="last"><div><input></div></td>
    </tr>    
</table>
```

Comment: Have you tried `last-child`?

Comment: It does not matter how to select; as you could see, selection is made ok. the question is, how to set the border?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```css
body {
  background: #3a7;
}
td.last {
  font-size: 1rem;
  empty-cells: show;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
  padding: 0px;
  color: #000;
  border: 0px solid transparent;
  overflow: visible;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0px solid transparent;
  overflow: visible;
}
input {
  border: 0px;
  outline: 0px transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: inherit;
  margin: 5px;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) div {
  background: white;
}
tr:nth-child(even) div {
  background: black;
}
.last > div {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><div><input></div></td>
        <td><div><input></div></td>
        <td class="last"><div><input></div></td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
        <td><div><input></div></td>
        <td><div><input></div></td>
        <td class="last"><div><input></div></td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
        <td><div><input></div></td>
        <td><div><input></div></td>
        <td class="last"><div><input></div></td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
        <td><div><input></div></td>
        <td><div><input></div></td>
        <td class="last"><div><input></div></td>
    </tr>    
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to set the last cell's background to `none` and instead color the background of the input field and its border:

https://jsfiddle.net/e1fnoa34/

Answer (score 1):

You could make the last cell `background: none`, and give it `padding-left: 20px`.  Then wrap the cell's content in a `DIV` or `SPAN` and apply the background styling to the inner wrapper instead.

Not ideal, but unfortunately you can't vary the with of the table cell spacing, and margin is ignored for table cells.

Comment: Yes, now I've done it that way (almost, with additional divs).
But, maybe there's a way to leave rows transparent and to make odd/even background on the cells? Because there's a possibility to make left border transparent and different size.

Comment: You could also insert a blank cell with 20px width before the last cell, and set its background to transparent.

Comment: Not working. Tried that but it looks like cells are rendering after rows, and all I achieved is just a visible row background through transparent cell
http://jsfiddle.net/BbIKTOP/a549b6t1/17/

Comment: You just had an extra `{` in your CSS.  I adjusted your fiddle, now it works: http://jsfiddle.net/a549b6t1/18/

Comment: Yes, the solution in this fiddle is the same as proposed by @tojowe - to remove tr background and to move td selector to the tr odd/even selector, to make different background for cells, not rows. It's working, thank you!